# Why doesn't VSCode keep settings.json inside of ~/.vscode, where it keeps installed extensions?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

On MacOS, VSCode keeps installed extensions in one location - `~/.vscode` and user settings in a completely separate location - `~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/`.

What's the reason for using a separate location for user settings? Does keeping user settings in a separate location have any benefits over keeping them in the same location as the installed location, `~/vscode/`?

Comment: This would be better asked directly to MS. It's likely they're just using default storage locations provided by the OS.

Comment: @DaveNewton a lot of MacOS apps use `~/.${app-name}` for user settings (ex: Hyper), with VSCode, what's interesting is that they use that path (`~/.vscode`) but they don't keep user settings there.

Comment: I'm saying that they may use the OS's "home" directory for one chunk of stuff, and the default paths provided by the OS for things like data and logs, e.g., like supplied by `env-paths` for other things, maybe on purpose, maybe holdover from early days, maybe some other reason, which is why only MS is likely to know. Since in the end it's all just directory locations there would be no distinct advantage (at least under OS X, IIRC) but under Windows (also IIRC) keeping them in the user dirs enables automagic roaming, and I don't know if the home dir follows users around. It might.

Comment: @DaveNewton Sure, it could be a reason that only MS knows about, but I'm hoping that it's a reason that more people know about and are willing to share here.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3884

Comment: Which leads me to believe one of the things I said above: historical.

Comment: @DaveNewton that's a great find! Thanks!